# Cannot assign to property: function call returns immutable value

Tags: swift

Consider the following example.

```
struct AStruct{
    var i = 0
}

class AClass{
    var i = 0
    var a: A = A(i: 8)

    func aStruct() -> AStruct{
        return a
    }
}
```

If I try to mutate the the variable of a instance of class `AClass` it compiles successfully.

```
var ca = AClass()
ca.a.i = 7
```

But If I try to mutate the return value of `aStruct` method, the compile screams

```
ca.aStruct().i = 8 //Compile error. Cannot assign to property: function call returns immutable value.
```

Can someone explain this.

Comment: What type is 'A' here? Have you misspelt 'AStruct' as 'A'?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is compiler's way of telling you that the modification of the `struct` is useless.

Here is what happens: when you call `aStruct()`, a *copy* of `A` is passed back to you. This copy is *temporary*. You can examine its fields, or assign it to a variable (in which case you would be able to access your modifications back). If the compiler would let you make modifications to this temporary structure, you would have no way of accessing them back. That is why the compiler is certain that this is a programming error.

Comment: exactly. the `struct` is useless in this case.

Answer (score 10):

Try this.

```
var aValue = ca.aStruct()
aValue.i = 9
```

Explanation

`aStruct()` actually returns a copy of the original struct `a`. it will implicitly be treated as a constant unless you assign it a `var`.

Comment: Got it now. implicitly treating as constant is the point I missed.

Answer (score 7):

Try using a `class` instead of a `struct`, as it's passed by reference and holds onto the object, while a `struct` is passed by value (a copy is created).