# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type

Tags: swift, struct

I have following struct:

```
public protocol SuperModel {
    // empty protocol
}
struct ModelOne: SuperModel {
    struct SubModelOne {
        var someVar: Double
        var othervar: Double?
    }
    var sub: SubModelOne?
    mutating func setSub(sub: SubModelOne) {          
        self.sub = sub
    }
}
```

In my class, I want to use this struct like that:

```
final class SomeClass: SuperClass {
    var data: SuperModel
    init() {
        self.data = ModelOne()
    }
    func someFunc() {
        (self.data as! ModelOne).setSub(ModelOne.SubModelOne(someVar: 2, otherVar: 1))
    }
}
```

I get following error: `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type 'ModelOne'`. Why is that so and how can I fix this?

Comment: What is NetworkCheckModel? A self-contained example would be useful.

Comment: try this 
var data = self.data as! ModelOne data.setSub(ModelOne.SubModelOne(someVar: 2, othervar: 1))

Comment: @MartinR sorry I was in a rush and forget to change it. Edit was made

Comment: @SahilBeri this works, but that means i would have a copy of it. Can I do `self.data = data` do copy it back?

Comment: You can do it  self.data = data but then you will not able to call setSub func using only self.data . only then you can call only those which is define in SuperModel protocol.

Comment: > by doing this var data = self.data as! ModelOne you are getting object of ModelOne which reference is you assigning to data variable and calling the setSub function. - @SahilBeri you are very close to right answer, but by some mistake. You think that structs are reference types, but if so - original code should work. Structs are value types.

Comment: ohh sorry i did it by mistake .

Comment: basically a copy of the ModelOne is made, and this new copy is assigned to data.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

When you apply type casting to value types (such structs), if succeed, you receive immutable *copy* of requested value:

```
(self.data as! ModelOne) // this is copy of data
```

The only way (as known to me) how you can mutate values that need to be casted - reassign value (as @Sahil Beri pointed you need declare variable):

```
func someFunc() {
    if var data = data as? ModelOne {
        data.setSub(ModelOne.SubModelOne(someVar: 2, otherVar: 1))
        self.data = data // you can do this since ModelOne conforms to SuperModel
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat solution. Also works for when using protocols to customize UI.

Answer (score 2):

Use like this,

```
struct UserAttributes {
    var name:String?
    var organizationID:String?
    var email:String?
    
    mutating func parseUserAttributes(attribues:[AWSCognitoIdentityProviderAttributeType])->UserAttributes{
        
        for type in attribues{
            if type.name == "name"{
                name = type.value
            }else if(type.name == "family_name"){
                organizationID = type.value
            }else if(type.name == "custom:role_id"){
                role = type.value
            }else if(type.name == "email"){
                email = type.value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In some other file call like this,

```
var userAttributes = UserAttributes()
userAttributes = userAttributes.parseUserAttributes(attribues:attributes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you have declared `data` as `SuperModel` but allocate it as `ModelOne`. Declare `data` as `ModelOne`. Then the problem goes away.

```
final class SomeClass: SuperClass {
    var data: ModelOne
    init() {
        self.data = ModelOne()
    }
    func someFunc() {
        (self.data).setSub(ModelOne.SubModelOne(someVar: 2, otherVar: 1))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First downcast the self.data to ModelOne then call setSub function

```
 if var data = self.data as? ModelOne {
   data.setSub(ModelOne.SubModelOne(someVar: 2, othervar: 1))
 }
```

Comment: as @ShadowOf wrote in his answer, I need to copy the value back to self.data

Comment: you can do this by self.data = data as i mentioned in comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

@Shadow of is right. You try to mutate a temporary structure which is impossible and most of the time useless as it will be released once the mutation done. It's in fact a similar issue to trying to modify the return struct of a function. (see answer here : [Cannot assign to property: function call returns immutable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113951/cannot-assign-to-property-function-call-returns-immutable-value))

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, in my case, I was able to resolve the error just by changing `struct` to a `class` object.

Comment: Should not do that in Swift.

Comment: Yes, of course you fix it! But this isn't a smart approach to do it. Check https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/

Comment: This solved my issue where I was looping through and array of objects that contained another object that i needed to modify.