# Changing a value in a shopping list using didSelectItemAt Indexpath

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[Text](https://github.com/kelson99/ios-sprint-challenge-shopping-list)

I cannot figure out how to change the label text on my collection view cell when the user presses the cell, from "not added" to "added" the model is a struct.

Please reference my repo for more information.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    shoppingListController.shoppingItems[indexPath.item].itemHasBeenAdded.toggle()
}
```

This is what I have so far but is giving me an error saying that it is an immutable value.

Comment: Git hub repo link [(https://github.com/kelson99/ios-sprint-challenge-shopping-list)]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the ShoppingItem construct from struct to class type to mutate the value of variable of ShoppingItem.
[To have greater insights check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764003/cannot-use-mutating-member-on-immutable-value-of-type)