# Update a struct array inside an array of struct

Tags: swift, xcode, struct, append

i am becoming crazy with a problem.
I would like to populate an array with structured datas where one of this value is an array of structured datas. The values would be taken by a json result structured as follow

```
{
   "values": [
        {
            "a": "Avalue",
            "b": "Bvalue",
            "c": [
                {
                    "d": "DValue",
                    "e": "EValue",
                    "f": "FValue",
                },
                {
                    "d": "Dvalue",
                    "e": "EValue",
                    "f": "FValue",
                }
             ],
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

so i have this code (schematized)

```
class CreateArray: UIViewController {
    struct FirstStruct {
        var a: String
        var b: String
        var c: [SecondStruct]

    }   
    struct SecondStruct {
        var d: String
        var e: String
        var f: String
    }
    var firstArray : [FirstStruct] = []
    var secondArray : [SecondStruct] = []
    var firstsArray = [[Any]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        populateArrays()


    }
    func populateArrays() {
        for value in values {     //don' t focus on schematized for loops
            for cs in value.c {
                self.secondArray.append(SecondStruct(d: "Dvalue", e: "Evalue", f: "Fvalue"))
            }    
            self.firstArray = [FirstStruct(a: "Avalue", b: "Bvalue", c: self.secondArray)]
            self.firstsArray.append(self.firstArray)
        }
    }

}
```

Now i have firstsArray made of multiple firstArray with secondArray as c' s value.
What i am looking for is a way to append another secondArray to a c of a specific firstArray, i am able to iterate to the right firstArray in firstsArray with something like that

```
for elem in firstsArray {
    if elem is the right one {
        create a secondStruct
        elem.c.append(created second struct)
    }
}
```

The problem is that i didn' t found a working way to append the new structured datas to the existing c. The most common problem i had is "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type [CreateArray.SecondStruct]"
i have also tried to add mutating func in the struct but nothing to do, but maybe i used it in the wrong way.
I am sure i was not totally clear, so please feel free to ask more infos.
Thanks a lot

**EDIT:**
I was able to find out a solution thenks to @New Dev suggest.
i have added a mutating func in the first Struct so now it is so:

```
struct FirstStruct {
    var a: String
    var b: String
    var c: [SecondStruct]
    mutating func updateC(latestC: SecondStruct) {
        c.append(latestC)
    }
}
```

Now i used this next in a function with for loops to find out the wanted firstArray and modify it (i think it is a replacement to be honest), using something like this

```
for index in self.firstsArray.indices {
    for secondindex in self.firstsArray[index].indices {
       if (self.firstsArray[index][secondindex] as! FirstStruct).a == WANTED A VALUE {
           if var updatingC = self.firstsArray[index][secondindex] as? FirstStruct {

               updatingC.updateC(latestC: (SecondStruct(d: "DValue", e: "EValue", f: "FValue")))


               self.firstsArray[index][secondindex] = updatingC
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764003/cannot-use-mutating-member-on-immutable-value-of-type. Is there a reason your `firstsArray` is using `Any`?

Comment: Great!!! Thanks a lot @NewDev using the mutating func combined with var declaration of the struct which i was working on did the trick. i will now update the question with fixed issues.