# Getting isn't mutable error while looping through an array and changing its property

Tags: arrays, swift, mapping, mutable

I'm looping through an array of basketball players where their id is equal to a certain player's id. Then i want to add +1 to the `fouls` property of the player object.

```
self.match.matchState.homePlayers.first{$0.id == toPlayer.id}?.fouls += 1
```

I have the error

> Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: function call returns immutable value

The `fouls` property is an optional integer. `var fouls: int?`
Even when i changed the `Player` struct to a class type i have another error.

> Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: function call returns immutable value

So how am i supposed to loop in an array of objects and change a certain property in it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot assign to property: function call returns immutable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113951/cannot-assign-to-property-function-call-returns-immutable-value)

Comment: @MoAbdul-Hameed i saw this question before but even though when i change the `Player` struct to a class i still have the same issue.

Comment: It shouldn't give you that error using a class.. Here is a simple example:

`class Player {
    let id: Int
    var fouls: Int
    
    init(id: Int, fouls: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.fouls = fouls
    }
}

let player1 = Player(id: 1, fouls: 2)
let player2 = Player(id: 1, fouls: 3)
let player3 = Player(id: 1, fouls: 4)

let homePlayers = [player1, player2, player3]

homePlayers.first{$0.id == 1}?.fouls += 1`

Comment: Just change `Player` to a class and make sure `fouls` is not a constant.

Comment: Fouls is not a constant it is `var fouls: Int?` but wait the error this time i think it's different. "Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: function call returns immutable value" there is the inout issue.

Comment: If you were trying to pass a `Player` instance anywhere in your code as an `inout` parameter you should now remove the `inout` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `Player` type from struct to class
then i found a way around to updated the `Player` object `fouls` property this way and it is working fine now with no errors

```
if toPlayer.fouls == nil {
   self.match.matchState.homePlayers.first{$0.id == toPlayer.id}?.fouls = toPlayer.fouls! + 1
}
```